# css not updating even after deleting cache/hard refresh

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

im trying to add an id to my contact section element in my page ! but it just doesn't update !
adding anything new to my css won't work, but modifying selectors that are already loaded in the page is possible !
The selector is written with background-color property and other things, but when i inspect the element (developer tool) , i can't see the selector and properties i already defined. But other old selectors are shown perfectly...
here's a picture:
[here's the dev-tool screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EprGm.png)

What i tried :
I tried to use a class instead of ID, didn't work.
Tried to change version by adding ?v.1 ?v.2  and ?version=15 ... every time i modify, didn't work.
Tried every type of cache reload and delete, didn't work.
Tried to open the page in the browser manually (open htdocs/myproject/index.html nd double click it), not by the local server (xampp localhost), didn't work.
Tried all available web browsers, doesn't work.
Tried to open the project in another pc , it doesn't work too.
Th

HERE'S THE WHOLE HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6ab5be8f07.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;1,300;1,400;1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles1.css">

        <title>portfolio</title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        
            <section id="firstbg">
                <div class="container">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  ">
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">portfolio</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Photography</a>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Wedding</a>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Landscapes</a>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Product photography</a>
                                </div>
                              </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About me</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link " href="#">Booking</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </nav>
                    <h2>badr kahouaji</h2>
                    <h4>hire a professional photographer</h4>
                    <!-- <div class="bluedivider"></div> -->
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">About me</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Bookings</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section id="story">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mystory">
                                <h2>My story</h2>
                                <div class="reddivider"></div>
                                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/home/portrait.jfif">
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </section>
            <section id="portfolio">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
                    <div class="bluedivider mx-auto"></div>
                    <div class="row pfrows">
                        <div class="col-xl-8 img">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/home/2.jfif">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-4 text textright">
                            <div >
                            <h3>Shoreline</h3>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled </p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row pfrows">
                        <div class="col-xl-4 text textleft">
                            <div >
                            <h3>Shoreline</h3>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled </p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-8 img">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/home/2.jfif">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row pics">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 img">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/home/2.jfif">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 texttwo">
                            <div class="first" >
                            <h3>tessttt</h3>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 texttwo">
                            <div class="nth">
                                <h3>test</h3>
                                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</p>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 img">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/home/2.jfif">
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section id="contacts">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 ">
                            <i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt"></i>
                            <h2>test</h2>
                            <p>4923 Market Street. Orlando FL</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>




        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

HERE'S THE WHOLE CSS:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.bluedivider{
        height:3px;
    width:100px;
    background-color: #191970;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.pfrows{
    margin:3% 0 3% 0;
}

/* navbar */
nav{
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
nav li{
    padding:5%;
}
nav a{
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color : #003bae;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.dropdown-menu{
    top:60%!important;
    padding: 4px;

}
.dropdown-item{
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}


/* firstbg */

#firstbg{
    background-image: url("../img/home/LSCAPE1.jpeg")  ;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size:cover;
    /* background-attachment: fixed; */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
}
#firstbg h2{
    padding-top:14%; 
    font-size: 700%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color : #fff;
}
#firstbg h4{
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color : #fff;
}
.buttons button{
    margin:4% 1% 4% 1%;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #3d59ab;
    border:3px solid #3d59ab;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding:12px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.buttons button:hover{
    background-color: #191970;
    border:3px solid #191970;
}

/* story */
#story{
    background-color :#0c0411;
}
.reddivider{
    height:3px;
    width:100px;
    background-color: #a20d5b;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.mystory{
    padding:15% 0% 15% 0%;;
    text-align: left;
}
.mystory h2{
    font-size: 60px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color : #fff;
}
.mystory p{
    color :#fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

/* PORTFOLIO */

#portfolio{
    padding:3%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;

}
#portfolio h2{
    font-size:35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    letter-spacing: .0625em;
}



.img{
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.text{
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
.textleft{
    border-right: .5rem solid #64a19d;
}
.textright{
    border-left: .5rem solid #64a19d;
}
.pfrows{
    background-color: rgba(61,89,171,.6);

}

.text h3{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color : #fff;
    line-height: 1.2;
    letter-spacing: .0625em;
}
.text p{
    color:rgba(0,0,0,.5)!important
}
.texttwo{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:130px;
};

#contacts{
    background-color : #000; 
}

----------
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening ??

Comment: Check that you're editing the right CSS file and that it's actually being included in your HTML. You want to be editing `css/styles1.css` which is relative to where your HTML is being served from.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code. It works for me. I include both html file and css in same folder. So I change the path as `href="styles1.css"`in html file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what your problem is.

I tried the code myself and watched the same behavior. You want the background to be black and it just won't.

Well, I think the problem is there's a more important CSS rule blocking your:

```
#contacts{ background-color: #000; }
```

rule.

I found out that if you move that rule to the top of the CSS file, you'll get your black background.

I suggest you check it out, and find out what rule is blocking your black #contacts section background.

[image]

In the picture I show you, I moved the #contacts rule up (to line 7), so now it's the second rule and it just works. The background is black.

Of course, now you should set your font color to a brighter one ! :)